# phpMyAdmin shows could not save configuration with "#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'" error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin via XAMPP on MacOS, when I access phpMyAdmin for the first time I get the error:

```
Could not save configuration
#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I have seen other answers with this issue, but for those answers it is based on it appearing when someone is trying to create a table/insert to a table, my message just appears on accessing phpMyAdmin or if I refresh the window.

I feel like it may be related to one of the table structures being incorrect, but how can I track down exactly which part of the database is causing this?

Thank you,

[image: Could not save configuration #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY']

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when you didn't checked the AI(auto-increment)checkbox while creating primary key in a table , so when you insert data in your table the primary key's value did not increment, that is why you get this error .

Check  the primary key of the table in which you are inserting data and check the unchecked AI checkbox of that primary key .